# How to copy AWS EC2 data to Azure Blob storage every day

Tags: amazon-ec2, azure-blob-storage, qliksense

Our Client is using Qlik Jobs which generates some data files in the same AWS EC2 instances.
The data has to be consumed by ETL pipelines in Azure.
A client wants the data to copy to Azure Blob Storage as and when Qlik Jobs executions are completed.
What are the options available here?

Answer (score 1):

Probably its easier to write some script (js, python etc) that copies the files to Azure. Then schedule [external program tasks](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-admin/February2022/Subsystems/DeployAdministerQSE/Content/Sense_DeployAdminister/QSEoW/Administer_QSEoW/Managing_QSEoW/create-edit-external-program-tasks.htm) to run the script after the task, that generates the qvd files, is successfully complete.

P.S. Personally i would go with NodeJS script. If you have Qlik installed then you have Node available as well. And no need to install anything extra. The exe is found in `qlik-install-folder\ServiceDispatcher\Node\node.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I assume based on your wording that your client is using **Qlik Sense Enterprise on Windows** (as opposed to Qlik Cloud) and is managing Qlik app reloads using the QMC and/or QRS API.

If that is indeed the case then I would echo Stefan's answer, where you write a PowerShell or Node script that is triggered by the successful reload of any Qlik apps that generate and store those files to the EC2 instance.

Here's a sample PowerShell script that you could use:

```
<#  ==== UPLOAD QVD FILES TO AZURE BLOB STORAGE ====
    Requirements:
        - Have the Azure PowerShell module installed on any Qlik Sense server that can run reloads
            - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-9.4.0
        - Set up certificate-based authentication, or similar, for connecting to Azure service
            - # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-9.4.0#certificate-based-authentication
        - Have an Azure Blob container set up
            - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-containers-powershell#list-containers
        - Have a blob set up
            - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-powershell#upload-a-blob
#>

# Set the directory path for the EC2 instance where the QVD files are being stored
$ec2_file_dir_path = $env:TEMP

# Filter to just those QVD files
$qvd_files = Get-ChildItem -Path $ec2_file_dir_path -Filter "*.qvd"

# Filter to only those QVDs that have been upadted in the last 10 minutes
# **You could certainly tighten this filter up to be more precise**
$only_new_qvd_files = $qvd_files | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10) }

# Authenticate to Azure with certificate
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "my_service_principal_id" -Tenant "my_tenant_id" -CertificateThumbprint "<thumbprint>"

# Get the requisite Azure Storage context and container
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "my_storage_account_name"
$ctr = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name "MyContainer" -Context $ctx

# Upload each QVD file to the required blob
$only_new_qvd_files | ForEach-Object {
    Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $_ -Container $ctr.Name -Context $ctx
    # You could do clean-up here, like updating metadata or deleting old files, etc.
}
```

If, however, your client is actually using **Qlik Cloud**, they could probably just use the included [Azure Storage connector](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Web_Storage_Provider_Connectors_help/Content/Connectors_StorageProvider/Storage%20provider%20connectors/Azure-Storage-storage-provider-connector.htm) to store those files to the EC2 instance *and* the Azure Storage environment in one go, no external scripts needed.